# SQL Query: Number of Districts each Country has?

Tags: mysql, sql, country

Trying to write a query that will provide the name of the country and the number of districts that country has as well order the results by the
number of districts from highest to lowest.The problem is that I can't figure out how to specifically count the number of districts for each country and end up getting the total number of districts beside one country, and nothing else...

The two tables are Country (which contains Name, Code) and City (which contains Name, District, CountryCode).

Country.Code and City.CountryCode are the same, that's what the two tables have in common.

THANKS so much for any help!

Comment: `JOIN` the tables, do a `GROUP BY`, use `COUNT(*)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 SELECT Name, noofdistricts
   FROM 
      (  SELECT c.Name,COUNT( ci.District ) AS noofdistricts
           FROM Country c
           JOIN City ci
             ON c.code = ci.countrycode
          GROUP BY c.Name
       ) Z
 ORDER BY Name,noofdistricts DESC
 ;
```

Comment: I was missing the group by statement. How do I go further to also order these results by noofdistricts descending? Order by doesn't seem to work alongside group by

Comment: I added the order by clause. pls check now

Comment: This is what I had word for word but it's still not sorted. Can't see a problem though

Comment: Give a try now...

Comment: "Every derived table must have it's own alias"

Comment: Sorry, only started sql yesterday..

Comment: No problem...try now... added alias

Comment: I removed Name from the ORDER BY statement and it worked, thank you

Comment: Np.. if you liked the soln.. pls upvote the up arrow...

Answer (score 0):

Then do a `JOIN` followed by `GROUP BY` like

```
select c.Name,
count(cc.District) as total_district
from country c join city cc on c.code = cc.CountryCode 
group by c.Name
order by total_district desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you are looking for something like this (counts how many unique districts are there in a country, based on info from City table):

```
select
  districts.country_name as country_name,
  count(districts.district) as district_count
from (      
  select unique --we want to count how many unique districts are there in a given country
    country.code as country_code,
    country.name as country_name,
    city.district as district --we want to get districts where cities are located
  from 
    Country country,
    City city
  where city.CountryCode = country.Code --join cities to countries
) districts
group by districts.country_code
order by district_count desc
```